# Row reordering in Angular material mat-table using drag events

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I am developing a website where I am using [Data Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) component of [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/). I want the user to be able to set some kind of priority to each row by dragging rows up and down. Something similar to [Data Table for jQuery](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/rowReorder). I cannot find support for reordering using drag events in their documentation. How can I achieve this functionality while adding least dependencies to my project?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Thanks.

Comment: I made changes to the design and ditched the Data Table and styled a simple list over which we used (ng2-dragula)[https://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/] package to help in reordering

Comment: thanks. I'm still using the mat-table and I'm using ng2-dragula as well. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you got ng2-dragula to work with material tables?

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for an answer on how to use this with Angular Material tables (mat-table):

Instead of using `<table mat-table ...>` you will have to use the `<mat-table ..>` selector. The former will have a `tbody` element between the table element (where you applied your dragula bag) and the rows. Attempting to drag the rows will instead make dragula pick up the `tbody` element. For `<mat table ...>` however, the rows will be immediate child elements of the container.

You can then use dragula like so:

```
<!-- my-table.component.html -->
<mat-table 
    [dragula]='"my-bag"' 
    [dataSource]="myTableDataSource">
    <!-- your column and row defs go here -->
</mat-table>
```

In your component

```
// my-table.component.ts
constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
  dragulaService.drop.subscribe((value) => {
    this.onDrop(value);
  });
}

private onDrop(args) {
    console.log(args);
}
```